# PHP mail() strange additional information automatically sending

Tags: php, email

Well, recently, I created a script and placed it up on a domain I have access to. Once I attempted to send an email, the email went through, no problem, but there was a thing that I found strange.

My subject field isn't being set. My subject line is completely blank as if I never sent one. It also doesn't seem as if my headers are being sent through either. (See this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS3Vy.png))

Also, is there a reason why these things are sent in the email along with my message? Like, could it possibly be a setting in php.ini?

> Message-Id: message-id-here@**.gs
>
> Date: Wed,  2 Jan 2013 05:37:47 +0400 (MSK)
>
> From: www-data@**.gs (www-data)
>
> Return-Path: www-data@**.gs
>
> X-OriginalArrivalTime: 02 Jan 2013 01:37:47.0814 (UTC)
>   FILETIME=[C5131C60:01CDE889]
>
> I'm sending an email, and this is the message.
>
> Is this going through correctly?

Currently, this is what my script looks like.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Email</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php
        ini_set("mail.add_x_header", "Off");
        if(isset($_POST['send']))
        {
            $To = ((isset($_POST['to'])) ? $_POST['to'] : '');
            $Subject = ((isset($_PST['subject'])) ? $_POST['subject'] : '');
            $Message = ((isset($_POST['message'])) ? $_POST['message'] : '');
            $Headers = ((isset($_POST['from'])) ? "From: " . $_POST['from'] . "\r\n" : '');
            $Headers = ((isset($_POST['reply-to'])) ? "Reply-to: " . $_POST['reply-to'] . "\r\nReturn-Path:" . $_POST['reply-to'] . "\r\n" : '');
            if(mail($To, $Subject, $Message, $Headers))
            {
                echo 'Sent to ' . $To . '.';
            }
        }
    ?>

    <form method="POST">
        To: <input type="text" name="to" value="" /><br />
        Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" value="" /><br />
        Message: <textarea name="message" style="width:300px; height:200px;"></textarea><br />
        From: <input type="text" name="from" value="" /><br />
        Reply-To: <input type="text" name="reply-to" value="" /><br />
        <input type="submit" name="send" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your subject isn't set because you have a typo. Change:

```
$Subject = ((isset($_PST['subject'])) ? $_POST['subject'] : '');
```

to:

```
$Subject = ((isset($_POST['subject'])) ? $_POST['subject'] : '');
```

As for headers, your Return-To overrides From header. You should also change \r\n to \n as some email clients interpret \r\n as "end of all headers".

So, instead of:

```
$Headers = ((isset($_POST['from'])) ? "From: " . $_POST['from'] . "\r\n" : '');
$Headers = ((isset($_POST['reply-to'])) ? "Reply-to: " . $_POST['reply-to'] . "\r\nReturn-Path:" . $_POST['reply-to'] . "\r\n" : '');
```

Do:

```
$Headers = array();
if (isset($_POST['from']))
{
    $Headers[] = "From: " . $_POST['from'];
}
if (isset($_POST['reply-to']))
{
    $Headers[] = "Reply-to: " . $_POST['reply-to'];
    $Headers[] = "Return-Path: " . $_POST['reply-to'];
}
$Headers = implode("\n", $Headers) . "\r\n";
```

Comment: When you mentioned the "From" header, I automatically knew the problem. I didn't append on the $Headers variable. Thanks again! Hoping someone can help me on the information being passed in the message. Haven't found anything that could lead me to solving it.

Comment: I changed my answer. The new code should fix all your problems, so give it a go.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if there's any other issue